# Hosting Asp.Net web Api in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have downloaded an Web Api project from below link

```
http://www.agile-code.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/FirstAspNetWebApi_20120920.zip
```

I tried below steps to host it in IIS

1. I have opened the project in Visual Studio 2012 and Right clicked the project and click publish and I have choosen New profile and then I have choosen `File System` as Publish method and configuration as Release and clicked publish
2. Now I opened IIS Manager and right clicked website and added option as below

[image]

Then I choose browse option by right clicking the application under sites folder and it shows error HTTP error 503: service unavailable
Can any one tell me why?

Comment: Folder permissions checked?

Comment: I have checked the folder permission and I have given full control for Everyone